# Why having this as a separate process causes all sorts of weirdness

Tags: debugging, vhdl

I'm learning VHDL, and what better way to learn than to have a project in it. So, the part of my project now is creating a little memory component.

Here is my full code:

```
entity memory is
  port(
    Address: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); --memory address
    Write: in std_logic; --write or read
    UseTopBits: in std_logic;  --if 1, top 8 bits of data is ignored and not written to memory
    Clock: in std_logic;
    DataIn: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    DataOut: out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    Reset: in std_logic
  );
end memory;

architecture Behavioral of memory is
  constant SIZE : integer := 4096;
  type memorytype is array(0 to (size-1)) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  signal mem: memorytype;

begin
  resetmem: process(Clock, Reset) --this process is the troublemaker 
  begin
  if(Reset ='1' and rising_edge(Clock)) then
    mem <= (others => "00000000");
  end if;

  end process;
  writemem: process(Reset,Write, Address, UseTopBits, Clock)
    variable addr: integer;
  begin
    addr := conv_integer(Address);
    if(addr>size-1) then
      addr:=0;
    end if;
    if(Write='1' and Reset='0') then
      if(rising_edge(clock)) then
        mem(conv_integer(addr)) <= DataIn(7 downto 0);
        if(UseTopBits='1') then
          mem(conv_integer(addr)+1) <= DataIn(15 downto 8);
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
  readmem: process(Reset,Address,Write,Clock)
    variable addr: integer;
  begin
    addr := conv_integer(Address);
    if(addr>size-1) then
      addr:=0;
    end if;
    if(Reset='1') then
      DataOut <= (others => '0');
    elsif(Write='0') then
      DataOut <= mem(conv_integer(addr)+1) & mem(conv_integer(addr));
    else 
      DataOut <= (others => '0');
    end if;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Before adding the Reset process, my code was working fine according to my test benches. Now after adding it I get all sorts of weirdness on `DataOut`. Seemingly random bits will have the logic state of `X` instead of a `0` or `1` and this causes all of my testbenches to fail (as it should)

I fixed it by putting the code into the `writemem` process as so:

```
begin
  --where resetmem process was
  writemem: process(Reset,Write, Address, UseTopBits, Clock)
    variable addr: integer;
  begin
    addr := conv_integer(Address);
    if(addr>size-1) then
      addr:=0;
    end if;
    if(Reset ='1' and rising_edge(Clock)) then --code is now here
      mem <= (others => "00000000");
    elsif(Write='1' and Reset='0') then
      if(rising_edge(clock)) then
        mem(conv_integer(addr)) <= DataIn(7 downto 0);
        if(UseTopBits='1') then
          mem(conv_integer(addr)+1) <= DataIn(15 downto 8);
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;
```

So the issue is fixed now, but I don't understand why having resetmem as a separate process caused all of these odd problems. Can anyone shed some light as to how this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VHDL has this concept of "drivers" on signals.

Each process that writes to the signal (or part of it for a bus) creates a driver.  When multiple drivers are connected to a signal a "resolution function" is called which decides what the resultant value should be.  It happens that (for a first approximation) the resolution function for `std_logic` (and hence for a `std_logic_vector`s bits) produces Xs when drivers with opposing values (`1` and `0`) are driven onto a signal.  There is also a value called `Z` which is treated as a non-driving value which can be overridden by other values. (and there are `W`, `L` and `H`, but we'll leave those aside for now, and `U` for uninitialised)

This process:

```
resetmem: process(Clock, Reset) --this process is the troublemaker 
  begin
  if(Reset ='1' and rising_edge(Clock)) then
    mem <= (others => "00000000");
  end if;
end process;
```

Says (paraphrased)

> > > if (reset and clock) then drive zeros to mem

It *doesn't* say anything about what to do if the condition is false, and therefore it continues to drive zeros (for the rest of time).  When your other process drives values, they clash and produce `X`s

For simulation purposes, you *could* do

```
else
  mem <= (others => 'Z');
```

which would make it "drive" a high-impedance which the other process could override.

---

However I think what you are trying to do is *initialise* the RAM to all zeros.  FPGA RAMs cannot be reset with a signal to a particular value, but they can be *loaded* with values at configuration time.  The simulator knows nothing about the configuration process, you simulations are deemed to be happening after configuration has finished.

Therefore, one way to simulate this behaviour is to initialise the signal when you declare it:

```
signal mem: memorytype := (others => (others => '0'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two processes driving `mem` with different (non-`Z`) values at the same time - that is what is causing the 'X' values.

Also, if you plan on synthesizing your code, you might want to have a look at the recommended process templates for inferring flip-flops (if you're using Xilinx ISE, you can find these in Edit > Language Templates > VHDL > Synthesis Constructs > Coding Examples > Flip Flops). That will help you get your priorities right for your reset/clock enable pins, to get a design that maps efficiently to the FPGA hardware.

For instance:

```
if(Write='1' and Reset='0') then
  if(rising_edge(clock)) then
    mem(conv_integer(addr)) <= DataIn(7 downto 0);
    if(UseTopBits='1') then
      mem(conv_integer(addr)+1) <= DataIn(15 downto 8);
    end if;
  end if;
end if;
```

Depending on the intelligence of your synthesizer, this might put your clock enable (`Write`) on a "higher" priority than it actually exists in your FPGA - and there's a high risk of you adding code at a later point that will cause this to happen for sure.

If you write it as:

```
if(Reset='1') then
  --Do nothing, for now
elsif(rising_edge(clock)) then
  if(Write='1') then
    mem(conv_integer(addr)) <= DataIn(7 downto 0);
    if(UseTopBits='1') then
      mem(conv_integer(addr)+1) <= DataIn(15 downto 8);
    end if;
  end if;
end if;
```

Your code will be much cleaner, and it should also synthesize much better to the underlying hardware (at least in the case of Xilinx FPGAs).

Also, have a look at Ken Chapmans [Get your priorities right](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp275.pdf) white-paper.

Comment: And you can find a lot more here: http://www.xilinx.com/support/#nav=sd-nav-link-21102&tab=tab-ap - although it can be a bit hard to find the really good ones...;)